# Express-validator .getValidationResult()

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, express-validator

I'm working on a simple login for a web application, and can't seem handle `.getValidationResult()` correctly. I've spent quite a bit of time pouring over the npm documentation for express-validator, trying to find an answer in tutorials, and looking on sites like Stack Overflow without managing to find the answer to my question. Perhaps I just don't know the right question to ask.

I want to ensure that

1. the user submitted something that has the form of an email address,
2. that the password isn't empty. I then want to
3. sanitize the email before interacting with the DB later on, then
4. check to see if any of the first 3 procedures failed. If there were failures, return the user to the login page.

My question is **what is the correct way to use express-validator's `.getValidationResult()`?**

Here's the offending piece of code:

```
export let postLogin = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  req.assert("email", "Email is not valid").isEmail();
  req.assert("password", "Password cannot be blank").notEmpty();
  req.sanitize("email").normalizeEmail({ gmail_remove_dots: false });

  req.getValidationResult().then(function(result){
      if (result != undefined) {
        console.log(result.array();
        return res.redirect("/login");
      }
    });

//do other login related stuff
}
```

I'm guessing that something simple is causing my error here, but I can't seem to find what it is.

Comment: The validation result is always `!= undefined`. It provides access to an object which has a few ways to get the errors. See @turmuka's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It returns a promise for an object called ***Validation Object***. This object contains information about the errors that your application has had.

The explanation.

> Runs all validations and returns a validation result object for the
>   errors gathered, for both sync and async validators.

All it does is returning errors if there is one. Here is some example code returned by that function.

```
//The error object

{
  "msg": "The error message",
  "param": "param.name.with.index[0]",
  "value": "param value",
  // Location of the param that generated this error.
  // It's either body, query, params, cookies or headers.
  "location": "body",

  // nestedErrors only exist when using the oneOf function
  "nestedErrors": [{ ... }]
}
```

The function returns `isEmpty()` when there is no errors to display.

The function returns `.array([options])` if there are any errors. Errors are located in `[options]` array.

Check out [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator#validation-result-api) for the example code of what it might return.

**UPDATE**

You can also just use it like this, which is easier.
Please note that this is new API as of v4.0.0 release of express-validator.

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
//go to a link    

app.get('/myURL', (req, res, next) => {
      // Get the validation result\
      const errors = validationResult(req).throw();
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors }); //err.mapped() 
 });
```